# Using $.getJSON() with callback within a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to set up an object so that it has an encapsulated $.getJSON method. Here's my setup:

```
function Property(price, deposit){
  this.price = price;
  this.deposit = deposit;
  this.getMortgageData = function(){
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/index?p='+this.price+'&d='+this.deposit+'&c=?', function(data){
        this.mortgageData = data;
    });
  }
  return true;
}
```

Now the problem seems to be that I don't have access to 'this' inside the getJSON callback function which makes sense.

Is there a workaround for this type of function or am I just thinking about this totally the wrong way? I've only ever really coded using PHP OO before so JS OO is a bit new to me.

Other things I've tried are:

```
  function Property(price, deposit){
  this.price = price;
  this.deposit = deposit;
  this.getMortgageData = function(){
    this.mortgageData = $.getJSON('http://example.com/index?p='+this.price+'&d='+this.deposit+'&c=?', function(data){
        return data;
    });
  }
  return true;
}
```

But still,

```
var prop = new Property();
prop.getMortgageData();
// wait for the response, then
alert(prop.mortgageData.xyz); // == undefined
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first attempt is close, but as you said, you can't access `this` inside the callback because it refers to something else. Instead, assign `this` to another name in the outer scope, and access that. The callback is a closure and will have access to that variable in the outer scope:

```
function Property(price, deposit){
  this.price = price;
  this.deposit = deposit;
  var property = this; // this variable will be accessible in the callback, but still refers to the right object.
  this.getMortgageData = function(){
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/index?p='+this.price+'&d='+this.deposit+'&c=?', function(data){
        property.mortgageData = data;
    });
  }
  return true;
}
```