# How to encapsulate an AJAX call as an attribute of an Javascript object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encapsulation

I am trying to encapsulate an AJAX call inside of an object, and by following threads here on SO I have been able to create an object (`Product`) with two properties, `getval` (a function for the AJAX call) and `myobj` (an object containing the results of the AJAX call). When I console log the `Product` object it shows both properties with the expected attributes. However, when I console log just the `Product.myobj` property it comes back `undefined`. So, my first question is **why am I getting an undefined?** and the second **is this a hacky method and is there a better approach?**. Thanks from a newbie, here is my code:

```
var url = "http://mazihealth.com";

function callback(data) {}
var Product = {
    getval: function (url, callback) {
        $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?', function (data) {
            callback($(data.contents));
        });
    }
};
Product.getval(url, function (data) {
    Product.myobj = data.filter('div').children();
    console.log(Product.myobj); //Object[5]
});
console.log(Product) //Object with 2 properties
console.log(Product.myobj); //undefined
```

UPDATED CODE:
I fixed up the callback and now create the Product.myobj in the callback function. Is there a way to encapsulate the callback function inside the Product object to create the Product.myobj property?

```
var url = "http://mazihealth.com";  
var Product = {getval:function(url, callback) {                      $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' +    encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?', callback);
    }
};

function callback(data) {
  Product.myobj = $(data.contents).filter('div').children();
};

Product.getval(url, callback);
console.log(Product)  //Object with 2 properties
```

Answer to my question found here:
[Using $.getJSON() with callback within a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818615/using-getjson-with-callback-within-a-javascript-object)

I refactored my code in two minutes and had exactly the result I needed.

Comment: By what "following threads"? Please link them.

Comment: Why did you declare that empty `function callback`?

Comment: What did you consider to be the "maybe hacky method", to `console.log(Product)` and [wait before you inspect it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync/23392650#23392650), or to use the callback and `console.log(Product.myobj)` in there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020929/return-value-from-getjson-function

Comment: You should have a look at the canonical question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Yes, I looked at that one as well. Both were of help with the use of the callback function. I left my callback empty because I wasn't sure what to do within the function other than to retrieve the result.

Comment: The callback you left empty is irrelevant, it's not the one you call. You're calling the `callback` that is passed as a paramter to `getval`, which is the `function(data) { console.log(data.filter('div').children()); }`

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Product.myobj` will always be `undefined` unless the `jQuery.getJSON` `success` has been called

and since you immediately call `console.log` after running the `Product.getval` function then it will execute before the callback due to network delay.