# return json result to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to return javascript function value :

```
function GetUserName() {
                var returnUserName;
                $.getJSON('/claims/GetUserName', function (data) {
                    returnUserName = "Test";
                    return false;
                    //callback(returnUserName);
                });
                return returnUserName;
}
```

I am expecting "Test" as the return value but i am getting "undefined"

Comment: Why `c#` and `asp.net-mcv` tags?

Comment: `getJSON()` will make a asynchronous request

Comment: Ohhh, damn it - the first **A** from the AJAX acronym means **ASYNCHRONOUS**. So please stop trying to return values from functions and start thinking in terms of callbacks. Just forget this `return` keyword.

Comment: how i can rewrite the code

Comment: Read and digest the information in the duplicate.  It's the canonical Q&A for this issue, and the example question almost exactly matches your code here.

Comment: The question is now closed so can't post an answer. You can read the dupe. But here are a few pointers. Have your `GetUserName` take a parameter that will represent  a callback. And then invoke this callback in the AJAX success method. Don't try to return any values from it.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA: Please refer for know how callback work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818615/using-getjson-with-callback-within-a-javascript-object

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd That question is about a completely different issue, and should probably itself be closed as a duplicate of [this canonical Q&A for that particular issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).